# Is it possible to change a VkBuffer's size?

Tags: vulkan

How do you grow a `VkBuffer`'s size, as in the `VkBufferCreateInfo.size` ?
Should I destroy the buffer and make a new one or can I just bind more memory by calling `vkBindBufferMemory` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once a buffer is created the size is fixed for the lifetime of the vkBuffer. Once memory has been bound to a buffer that binding is set for the remaining lifetime of the vkBuffer. Even if you free the backing vkMemory, the buffer becomes unusable.

So yes you have to create a new vkBuffer to change either of these properties.

Comment: However, if you allocate more VkDeviceMemory than you need, you can destroy your original VkBuffer and create a new one, binding it to the original VkDeviceMemory including the portion that was previously bound to the first VkBuffer.

Comment: does that mean that I can even reuse the existing data in the device memory ?

Comment: @MacelaruTiberiu only if the new buffer can be bound to the same memory allocation. Otherwise you'll need to copy it.

Comment: @MacelaruTiberiu In general yes - data in memory stays intact when You destroy resources that were using this memory.